# Xamarin Forms show/hide option for entry

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I am working on Xamarin.Forms and wondering about any possibility to add show/hide option to an entry field?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved a similar issue by using an expand/collapse icon above a number of entry fields.

**The show/hide element in XAML**

Add a clickable image with fixed size(20x20) referring to embedded resources in the PCL:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ShowHideIcon, Converter={StaticResource StringToResImageSourceConverter}}" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowHideCommand}" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**The ViewModel processes the command:**

Switch the boolean every time the image is touched.

```
public bool EntryVisible { get; set; }

public Command ShowHideCommand{
    get {
        return new Command((object o) => {
            EntryVisible = !EntryVisible;
            if (EntryVisible) { 
                ShowHideIcon = "ic_collapse"; 
            } else { 
                ShowHideIcon = "ic_expand"; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The label and Entry in XAML**

Bind the IsVisible attribute of the Label and Entry to the boolean in the ViewModel.

```
<Label Text="Quantity" IsVisible="{Binding EntryVisible}" />
<Entry Text="{Binding Quantity}" IsVisible="{Binding EntryVisible}" />
```

For completeness sake, I have used https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images to store images `ic_expand.png` and `ic_collapse.png` in the PCL Resources folder.

A Converter is required to turn a string e.g. "ic_expand" into an image reference that XAML can use.

```
public class StringToResImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var resString = (string)value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resString)) {
            return ImageSource.FromResource("ProjectName.Resources." + resString + ".png");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
Entry entry = new Entry();

// Hide it
entry.IsVisible = false;
```